# How do I submit 3 forms with 1 submit button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I have a table that has X rows. I use an iterator to iterate over each object in a collection and render it in a row.

Each object/row is also associated with it's own form.

But I want to save the entire collection at once, and have it update all of the sub-forms when the user hits 1 submit button, rather than 1 for each instance of the form.

This is an example of what the code might look like:

```
<% @port_stocks.each do |port_stock| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= number_to_currency(port_stock.purchase_price) %></td>
            <td><%= port_stock.volume %></td>
            <td>
              <% cp = ClosedPosition.new %>
              <%= simple_form_for cp, url: port_stocks_sell_order_path, method: :post, html: { class: "form-inline" } do |f| %>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.input_field :num_units, id: "sell-ps-#{port_stock.id}", class: "form-control mx-sm-3" %>
                </div>
                <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
              <% end %>
            </td>
          </tr>
<% end %>
```

If there are 3 `port_stock` objects in the `@port_stocks` collection, the above form renders 3 submit buttons -- which is exactly what I don't want.

I just want 1 submit button that submits a `cp` related info for each `port_stock` object in the collection.

Comment: Can you consider to wrap the full table with the form_tag (or simple form) and build custom field names then manage a custom save process in the controller? I mean params could be something like `"closed_position"=>{"port_stock_id"=>{"1"=>{"num_units"=>"999"}, "2"=>{"num_units"=>"888"}}}`. In this way you can submit with just one button.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the submit button inside the simple_form like below:

```
<% @port_stocks.each do |port_stock| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(port_stock.purchase_price) %></td>
    <td><%= port_stock.volume %></td>
    <td>
      <% cp = ClosedPosition.new %>
      <%= simple_form_for cp, url: port_stocks_sell_order_path, method: :post, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input_field :num_units, id: "sell-ps-#{port_stock.id}", class: "form-control mx-sm-3" %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit "", class: "click-me", style: "display: none;" %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Then have a button outside the loop like this:

```
<button type="button" class='btn btn-primary' onclick="submit()">Submit!</button>
```

Onclick of this button use JS to trigger clicks on hidden submit buttons.

```
<script>
    function submit(){
      var el = document.getElementsByClassName('click-me');
      for (var i=0;i<el.length; i++) {
        el[i].click();
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Ideally though, I would love to have a non-JS solution. But I do like this as a backup in case I can't get one. Thnx!

Comment: I'm just excited to see what kind of solution you will end up with. The solution you're looking is for client-side and only JS could run on client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, following up my comment, using standard form helpers.
Wrap the table with the form:

```
<%= form_for :closed_position, url: {action: :port_stocks_sell_order_path, method: :post} do |form|%>
  <table>
      <% @port_stocks.each do |port_stock| %>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><%= port_stock.volume %></td>
              <td><%= port_stock.purchase_price %></td>
              <td>
                  Num: <%= form.text_field "port_stock_id[#{port_stock.id}][num_units]" %>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      <% end %>
  </table>
  <%= form.submit "save" %>
<% end %>
```

The parameters should be something like:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"blahblah", "closed_position"=>{"port_stock_id"=>{"1"=>{"num_units"=>"999"}, "2"=>{"num_units"=>"888"}}}, "commit"=>"save", "method"=>"post", "controller"=>"port_stocks", "action"=>"port_stocks_sell_order_path"}
```

Then manage to save each `ClosedPosition` in the controller.